# Saving data to a column without deleting others in a Django script

Tags: python, django

I have a model in the form of:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    some_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    data1 = models.IntegerField()
    data2 = models.IntegerField()
    data3 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

I'm reading in data from various files, and using header information to identify where the columns in said files should be saved.  Each column name in the database is unique, so I use them to point me to the appropriate table as well.

There are cases where a given row in the database will already contain columns with data, and I'll need to add data to other columns.  I'm running python code within the Django shell to do this.  However, if I specify a pk or 'some_id' for an existing element to save data into one column, data from all other columns in that row will be overwritten as None.  For example, if my code reads,

```
data_args = {}
data_args['some_id'] = 0
data_args['data2'] = 100

data_entry = Data(**data_args)

data_entry.save()
```

and data1 and data3 for that entry were already populated, after the save(), they would read None.

Because I'm running this from a script and my column names are being read as strings from a header, I haven't been able to figure out how to update the data in the form of the examples in the documentation, like:

```
data_entry = Data.objects.get(some_id=0)
data_entry.data2=100
data_entry.save()
```

While this works from the command line, it doesn't from python code when 'data2' is read as a string from a file header.

EDIT:  Apologies for the lack of clarity.  I was trying to spare some gory detail.  When I say the above (correct) code doesn't work in my script, I access the name of the column 'data2' from a file header that looks like:

```
some_id|data1|data2|data3
```

I parse the data in the file using numpy.genfromtxt, which provides access to the names of the data columns in the form:

```
data_array.dtype.names = ('some_id', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3')
```

So, assuming the first entry in Data already exists, if I try to save to a column with no data,

```
single_arg = data_array.dtype.names[2]
data_entry = Data.objects.get(some_id=0)
data_entry.single_arg = 100
data_entry.save()
```

the value 100 doesn't end up being saved into the 'data2' column of the first entry.  The value I get is still None.  In the loop in which I'm performing this operation, before the save(), I print up single_arg (which would show data2 in this example), the variable containing the value I'm trying to assign to data_entry.single_arg (100 in this example), and data_entry.single_arg itself (which should read 100 in this example), and they all look correct.

For some reason, however, the value does not get saved into the database.  If the above code is correct, then perhaps my problem does lie elsewhere.

FURTHER EDIT:

As I thought, the problem seems to be that single_arg isn't registering as 'data2' when used in data_entry.single_arg.  After the save(), if I re-query the database and try to print what should have been saved:

```
data_entry = Data.objects.get(some_id=0)
single_arg = data_array.dtype.names[2]
print data_entry.single_arg
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Data' object has no attribute 'single_arg'
```

So, it might be that while in the script the entire string "data_entry.single_arg" has a value of 100, the object data_entry.data2 isn't actually being accessed at all.  Maybe.

So my question is how can I save data into one column (or more) while preserving existing data in other columns in the same row?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when 'data2' is read as a string from a file header"? Can you give an example of the code that's doing this? As Dave and Brian say, your second example is correct, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing an attribute lookup with `getattr`. You can't resolve strings to attributes by typing `data.single_arg` - how would python know whether to use the variable value or the attribute name?

```
single_arg = 'data2'
data.single_arg = 100

# you can NOT set an attribute by a string this way. 
# You're just setting an attribute called single_arg to 100 which isn't a model 
# field, so it's not going to be saved.
```

To set an attribute via a string, you need to use `setattr`

```
single_arg = 'data2'
data = Data.objects.get(id=1)
setattr(data, single_arg, 100)
data.save()
```

Your last example is as expected.. `data_entry` has no `single_arg` attribute. You need to be calling `getattr(data_entry, single_arg)` if you want the string attribute referenced in the variable `single_arg`.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I was trying to understand what this "single_arg" was.. and then it hit me what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to your question is that when you do

```
data_entry = Data(**data_args)
data_entry.save()
```

you're saving a new record to the database; any values you don't populate will get the default values or NULL depending on the model field definitions. To modify an existing record, you have to first retrieve it from the database as in your second block of code:

```
data_entry = Data.objects.get(some_id=0) # populates data_entry object with values from db
data_entry.data2=100
data_entry.save()
```

If in your script this code appears to be overwriting your existing values, there's some other issue at work. I suggest printing out the values of the object when you first retrieve it from the database, as that might reveal that the problem lies further upstream. A convenient way to print all of a model instance's values is:

```
print data_entry.__dict__
```